# BigQuery - saving query with complete non flat schema

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a filter on an existing table (say tableA), and wish to save the result in a destination table (tableB) with the same schema.

tableA has a complex schema, with multiple nested hierarchies.
I'm using the "do not flatten results" and "allow large results" options on the following query:

```
select * from tableA where 
  property > 100
```

1. Is it possible to save a complex schema? Or will I be forced to flatten the result using the flatten keyword (assume the table has nested elements which are not nested one within the other)?
2. For this specific trial I get an explained error: Unexpected. Please try again.
   Job ID: 507322187707:job_r8hHPaz7Qiv7eMP89nbAsq46MzY

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you should be able to save a table with an arbitrarily complex schema with this option set.
2. You're hitting limits in some of our auxiliary operations we use to calculate the size of your result set.  This appears to be due to the size of the resulting schema.  I've filed a bug internally and will investigate further.